# Hibernate HQL - Get Entity next date from today

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I have several entries in the database.
For example.

Entity "Jobs"
This entity has the property "date".

Now I want to create a query. The result of the query is the NEXT Job from today.

An Example:

```
ID    NAME     DATE
1     Test1    2014-08-31
**2     Test2    2014-08-28**
3     Test3    2014-07-20
4     Test4    2014-12-20
```

The next data with the date (current Date today is: 2014-08-03). Now I should get the Date with ID 2.
How can I do this?

A special is: if there are Jobs with the same day and are the next Jobs.

How can I do this?
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select job from Job job where job.date > :today order by job.date desc
```

This query will return you all the jobs having a date bigger than the date passed as query parameter, from the soonest to the latest.

If you just want the first one, then call the [following method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29):

```
query.setMaxResults(1);
```

and the query will return a list of only one element: the first job.

Comment: Thank you. And how can I do this: if there are two or more jobs to set this to the result list?